# how to write a test for an authorized user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help advice.

I wrote the test for the action edit:

```
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)  
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_response :success
    assert_template :edit
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"           
  end
```

users.yml:

```
one:
  name: 'onfge'
  email: 'MyStrdfing@ad.ad'
  password_digest: '$2a$10$XS2HLwMZxg/7yRKAWd9AJ.afCMra0wGWK4b.FhkY/qo3Lmo/tKEiO'
  remember_token: 'dc3461e13c8d316dad22332a503e06edafa0b9cb'
  phone: '43535345'
  skype: 'gggggg'
  gender: one
  info: 'MyString'
  admin: true
  avatar_file_name: nil
  avatar_content_type: nil
  avatar_file_size: nil
```

The problem is that a page `/users/2/edit` access only the user authenticated. Now it is redirected to the authentication page.

please tell me how to implement a successful authentication in the test? I tried to do the following:

test/test_helper.rb:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

  module SignInHelper
    def sign_in(user)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  class ActionController::TestCase
    include SignInHelper
  end  
end
```

users_controller_test.rb:

```
  test "should get edit" do
    sign_in(@user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_response :success
    assert_template :edit
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"           
  end
```

but got into the console the following error message:

```
rake test:controllers
  1) Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_edit [/home/kalinin/rails/ZSUM/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:59]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>
```

for authentication i use SessionController:

```
  def create
    user  = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if  user  &&  user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome  to  the Sample  App!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid  email/password  combination'  
      render  'new'
    end    
  end
```

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Are you using devise?

Comment: no. i use custom code